# How to calculate probability of measuring $|1\rangle$ after application of $R_x$ gate

Tags: measurement, probability

I was trying to understand how to calculate
the probability of measuring $|1\rangle$ when executing the following circuit in Qiskit:

```python
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.rx(3*math.pi/4, 0)
```

The answer in the book states it’s 0.8536 but I can’t understand the logic behind this.

I tried with the matrix of the $R_x$ gate but I am unable to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You start out with $|0\rangle$.

You multiply that with

$ \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta/2) & -i \cdot \sin(\theta/2) \\
-i \cdot \sin(\theta/2) & \cos(\theta/2)
\end{bmatrix}  $

where $\theta=3 \pi/4$ , which gets you

$ \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta/2) \\
-i \cdot \sin(\theta/2) 
\end{bmatrix}  $.

Now you take the  lower entry of the vector to calculate your probability using $|x|²$.

Comment: Question 3: 
In the below code snippet, what is the probability of measuring |1>?

qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.rx(3*math.pi/4, 0)

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am just learning the things as well. This shuld be the way to solve now :)

Comment: So if I take sin 3 pi by 4, it would be |0.74|² which is not equal to 0.85.

Comment: You have an error in your calculation. You should put your calculation in the question

Comment: Note that when you put qc.rx(3*math.pi/4,0), you are setting $\theta = \pi/4$, so your bottom entry becomes $- i \cdot \sin(3\pi/8) $ i.e. don't forget to divide the angle by 2! And also separately there seems to be a slight confusion about the states, because if you do the calculation, the probability of measuring the $|0\rangle$ state should be about 0.86 (not the $|1\rangle$ state)